# Camel FTP client on Google cloud Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ftp, apache-camel

Trying to connect a Camel FTP client to an external server from google cloud Kubernetes.

The client just not doing anything.

Same exact setup works from the local machine.

```
2020-12-03 10:49:40.358  INFO 84475 --- [           main|                         ] o.a.c.i.e.InternalRouteStartupManager    : Route: c4876321-5e48-42e1-8c26-deab1868a172 started and consuming from: ftp://XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

```java
        onException(Exception.class)
            .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, this.getClass().getName(), "${exception.message} ${headers} ${body}")
            .handled(true);

        from("ftp:" + url)
            .routeId(key.toString())
            .description("loading FTP csv file")
            .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, this.getClass().getName(), "${headers} ${body}")
            .to(to);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with FTP access inside docker, not related to k8s strictly.

you need to add the *passive mode* **true** to your path query params under docker.

`passiveMode=true`